# Adding new user to Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I searched for a long time for **one full answer** on how to create users in Active Directory using C# and I can't find any.

I would like to know the steps *(including on where to specify AD credentials).*

I don't mind if the user gets created using `System.DirectoryServices` or `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`.

Here're the details. The `DC` is a remote computer *(sitting in my lan)*. For example, the domain name is `contoso-test.com`.

Comment: Where to "put" credentials is highly subjective, and the IP of the DC shouldn't be stored anywhere - you should locate it based on its name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of google search and patience will do the trick.

Here's a sample code I've written a while back.

```
public static string CreateUser(string username, string password)
{
    //CREATE CONNECTION TO ACTIVE DIRECTORY
    using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "contosco-test.com"))
    {
        //CREATE A NEW USERPRINCIPAL OBJECT
        using (UserPrincipal principal = new UserPrincipal(ctx))
        {
            principal.Enabled = true; //IF NOT ENABLED YOU CAN'T AUTHENTICATE THE USER
            principal.UserPrincipalName = username;
            principal.Name = "name";
            principal.DisplayName = "firstname lastname";
            principal.EmailAddress = "email@test.com";
            principal.VoiceTelephoneNumber = "12345678910";
            principal.GivenName = "firstname";
            principal.Surname = "lastname";
            principal.SetPassword(password);
            try
            {
               principal.Save();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)           
            {
                throw;
            }
            //SEARCH FOR THE USER THAT JUST HAS BEEN CREATED
            using (var newUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, username))
            {
                if (newUser != null)
                {
                   return newUser.Guid.ToString();
                }
            }
         }
    }
  return null;
}
```

I'm using `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void AddToGroup(string userDn, string groupDn)
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + groupDn);
        dirEntry.Properties["member"].Add(userDn);
        dirEntry.CommitChanges();
        dirEntry.Close();
    }
    catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException E)
    {
        //doSomething with E.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#36